# In a GitHub Actions workflow, how can you determine the Organziation where the current repository is housed?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm trying to organize my workflow artifacts (on a self-hosted runner) using a structure similar to this:

```
c:\github\artifacts\{org}\{repo}\{runid}
```

Different organizations in our enterprise COULD have a repository with the same name, so I wanted to be able to organize by organization name.

I have this so far:

```
c:\github\artifacts\{org}\{${{ github.event.repository.name }}\${{ github.run_id }}\
```

How can I determine the organization name?

Comment: Try **github.event.repository.full_name** which gives you both the org and repository name or **github.event.repository.owner.name** which is just the org.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get that from [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context). The repo name and the repository organization can be found with:

- ${{ github.repository }} (repo name)
- ${{ github.repository_owner }} (repo organization)

If you don't know what are the values and which env variables are available to runner, you can just run `env` in a step to print it out, like so:

```
name: Print environment variables

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  debug:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Print
        run: env | sort
```

Comment: ${{ github.repository_owner }} did it, thanks